# Probability of Cause of Death via Mortality Rate

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, bayes-theorem

Working on a statistics project, I wanted to get this correct. 
The suicide rate in the United States is $\frac{14}{100,000}/year$ 
If the United States has a population of $335 \cdot 10^6$, and there are $2,838,240$ deaths per year, this would result in $1.65\%$ of deaths. 
Probability of selected person eventually dying by suicide would be $1.65\%$, or $0.014\%$?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information:

- First, people live longer than a single year (for instance you, unless you're an amazing prodigy violating SE EULA)
- Second, whether a person commit suicide and how long he/she lives are (clearly) not independent events (people only commit suicides (successfully) in the last year of their lives)
- Third, the age of a person and whether he/she commits suicide are not independent events (not much people intentionally commit suicide at age 2; and unintententional suicides are not called suicides)

Hence we would need more data to determined said probability, likely requiring surveys.

---

In order to prevent the X-Y problem... what are you actually trying to accomplish?